# Express res.redirect is throwing an error in console

Tags: express

I am trying to redirect the user to a page, but it keeps on throwing the following error in console.

*Unsafe attempt to load URL  from frame with URL "source_url". Domains, protocols and ports must match.*

Redirect code:

```
export default (req, res) => {
  const redirectUrl = req.query.redirectUrl || '';
  console.log("########### LOGIN ###########" + req.query.redirectUrl);
  res.redirect(destination_url);
};
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the redirect code please?

Comment: Please share your code :)

Comment: What's the value of redirectUrl and the console.log output?

Comment: console.log() prints the exact URL I want to redirect to.

Comment: This creates a local variable named `redirectUrl` but it passes a completely different variable named `destination_url` as the argument to `res.redirect()`.  Where does `destination_url` come from and what does it contain?